# Are answers that aggregate information from other questions on Stack Overflow NAA?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, specific-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33106697/2415822) to [this bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33064329/2415822) is a collection of other answers from questions previously asked on Stack Overflow.  To me, answers that post links or information from other SO questions are NAA, because the question should be flagged as a duplicate if the question has already been asked and an answer exists.

What is the consensus on answers that link to or contain information from other Stack Overflow questions?
Are they not actually answers?

Comment: That clearly **is an answer**. You may not think it's a *good* answer, but it's definitely **not** NAA.

Comment: The first 2 actually come from apple.stackexchange, not from SO. So having them here is nice, as one might not find them. For example, I wasn't aware of a SE site dedicated to Apple until 2 weeks ago, I would have never looked there. Anyway, the most important part when an answer is taken from another place is giving proper credit, by linking the original source. In this case it has been done, so I'm fine with that.

Comment: ["Want to know an easy way to earn reputation? Find a question somewhere with several good, but incomplete, answers. Steal all the answers and write one long, complete, detailed answer which is better than the incomplete ones."](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html)

Comment: @BradLarson Note that what you've just described is different from simply finding common problems that have lots of duplicate questions and posting the same answer to all of those duplicates.

Comment: @BradLarson, Yep, I've done that before. I forget were I found the thread about it, but it said that if someone puts an answer in a comment, take the comment and make it your own answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it an *attempt* at answering the question?

If the answer is *yes* (Which it is), then "NAA" doesn't apply there.

The answers can still be incorrect, low quality, or flaggable for some other reason.
NAA should really *only* be used for post that *don't* attempt to answer the question:

- Comments posted as answer
- *"I have this problem too!"* - posts

Stuff like that.

While spam posts are often NAA, ***don't*** flag them as NAA. Flag it as spam.

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth would you ding an answer for **containing** information from other questions/answers? That's ridiculous. If there's a general Q/A pair somewhere that mostly applies to a specific situation, but also requires an additional note from somewhere else, and the answer consists of quoting those two answers* and adding a little bit of glue, that's perfectly fine. Upvote-worthy, even. Or, as in this case, aggregating multiple different approaches into a single easier-to-find answer is reasonable enough.

Now, if the questions are actually duplicates, that's another story; usually I see link-only answers that are basically dupe-flags or reposting the same answer from the same account multiple times, rather than quotes of others' answers, but in any case those should just be flags as duplicate, not answers. Since it's *impossible* to flag a question as a simultaneous duplicate of two off-site questions and one on-site, that's not relevant.

<sub>**Yes, with attribution.*</sub>

Comment: The answer didn't support its own original content with quotes from other answers.  It contains no original content at all; only quotes.  The two quotes aren't two halves of a complete answer, but rather two different people's answers to the same question, meaning that either these answers don't answer the question being asked, or the questions are duplicates.

Comment: @Servy: As previously noted, you can't flag a question as a dupe of three different questions on two different sites, so at *some* point, you're going to have to work out which answers are applicable and collect them together. It would be nice to split them apart and determine which conditions lead to which answers applying, certainly, but failure to do that is not grounds for deletion as "not an answer" (or, probably, at all).

Comment: I see no basis for assuming that all three answers are needed to answer the question.  The answers contain different approaches to solve the same problem.  One does not need to read every single one of the answers to solve the problem.  I never said that the answer is NAA, but it isn't an appropriate answer (for a different reason).

Comment: @Servy: Like I said, it would be nice if the answer gave conditions for using the different approaches, but just because it doesn't is no reason to delete it.

Comment: The fact that its adding zero value is a reason to delete it though.

Comment: @Servy: I have a higher bar for what merits deletion, apparently. Short of a thorough untangling effort that sorts out the four+ questions and resolves them as cross-site duplicates with a single optimum answer, there's no good reason to delete an answer that would qualify as the base for that.

Comment: So because someone could turn the useless answer into a good answer means that it's not useless?  It doesn't really work that way.

Comment: @Servy: It's not useless. That's all.

Comment: It's adding zero value.  It's just repeating already available information.  That's not useful.